# Execution of "required" code in php

Tags: php

I have some files:

**core.php**:

```
require_once 'logger.php';
require_once 'smth_else.php';

$Logger = new Logger();
$Else = new Smth_else();
```

**smth_else.php**:

```
...
$Logger->write(...);
...
```

And get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Logger in
>   smth_else.php...

Comment: your edit is a completely different question. Please, consider removing it and posting as a new question.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340222/php-and-some-global-variables

Comment: Not sure at all what this is.. a question.. a statement?

Comment: nikc, it's not a duplicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of setting the variables and requiring your files matters. This will work:

```
require_once 'logger.php';
$Logger = new Logger();
require_once 'smth_else.php';
$Else = new Smth_else();
```

Comment: It doesn't help me in updated code. Could you revise it, please?

Answer (score 2):

code in `'smth_else.php'` is executed on inclusion, that is at `require_once`. At that stage you don't have `$Logger` defined.

Answer (score 1):

You must define $logger **before** the inclusion of smth_else.php.
Think of an inclusion as is you were pasting it into the including context.