# PHP and some global variables

Tags: php, require-once

```
require_once'modules/logger.php';                                                         
$Logger = new Logger();

require_once 'templates/list.php';
$Templates = new templatesList();

require_once 'widgets/list.php';
$Widgets = new widgetsList();
```

I use `$Logger` in `templates/list.php` and in `widgets/list.php`.
`$Templates` I use in `/widgets/list.php`.

The code above throws this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: `Logger` in
>   `.../templates/list.php` on line 99
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   `toLog()` on a non-object in
>   `.../templates/list.php`  on line 99

**UPD**
Here is line 99:

```
$Logger->toLog( $contentData );
```

Comment: where is your line 99? Could you post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `$Logger` from within an object method, you will need to mark it as global within that method. If you don't you will end up creating a new local $Logger variable. I suspect that is what the problem is. For example:

```
class templatesList {
    public function __construct() {
        global $Logger;
        //now we can use $logger.
    }
}
```

However, it would probably be better to pass $Logger into the constructor of every object which needs to use it. Global variables are not generally considered good practise.

```
class templatesList {
    protected $Logger;
    public function __construct(Logger $Logger) {
        //now we can use $logger.

        //store reference we can use later
        $this->Logger = $Logger;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        $this->Logger->log('something');
    }
}

new templatesList($Logger);
```

Comment: I tried to use global keyword, it didn't help me. Maybe passing it into constructor will be better idea... Okay, thanks.

Comment: For a Logger and Templateslist class (which both sound like there needs only be one instance of each) I'd suggest using a singleton model. No need to pass variables or using globals.

Comment: While a singleton version of Logger might be appropriate, a singleton is just a global variable in disguise

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not unsetting $Logger somewhere in the beginning of /templates/list.php?

Try var_dumping() $Logger after its initialization and before using.